# how to change the color of wearOS scrollbar

Tags: android, scroll, scrollbar, wear-os

[image]

I want to change the color of scrollbar.

I tried to set in xml like this,

```
android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@color/blue"
```

or like this

```
app:fastScrollVerticalThumbDrawable="@drawable/scroll"
```

but it's not working.

please let me know if there is a way to change the color , thanks.

To explain more clearly

my code

```
<androidx.wear.widget.WearableRecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/barcodeRecyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:fadeScrollbars="false"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingStart="10dp"
    android:paddingEnd="10dp"
    android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
    android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/scrollview_thumb"
    android:scrollbarTrackVertical="@drawable/vertical_scrollview_track"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />
```

In my emulator, the code upon only change the original scrollBar. If I scroll page, the  original scrollBar(which been changed) would disappear and the curved scrollBar would pop up.

original scrollBar(I changed it into blue)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZEiB.png]

curved scrollBar

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YayRl.png]

Answer (score 0):

```
 1. Add following tags in your scrollview

android:fadeScrollbars="false"
android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/scrollview_thumb"
android:scrollbarTrackVertical="@drawable/vertical_scrollview_track"

 2. Create following drawable in your drawable folder

scrollview_thumb.xml

 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <solid android:color="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_light_focused" />
    <corners android:radius="15dp" />

    </shape>

3.vertical_scrollview_traack.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<solid android:color="#E2E0EB" />
<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="#b3a9a9" />
<size android:width="15dp" />
<corners android:radius="15dp" />
</shape>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering,

I’m afraid the problem is still the same.

In my emulator, the code upon only change the original scrollBar. If I scroll page, the  original scrollBar(which been changed) would disappear and the curved scrollBar will show.

original scrollBar(I changed it into blue) [https://i.imgur.com/IHwbb4h.png](https://i.imgur.com/IHwbb4h.png)

curved scrollBar. [https://i.imgur.com/oNy10TL.png](https://i.imgur.com/oNy10TL.png)